# Infinite Loop in Python decryption cipher

Tags: python, encryption, infinite-loop

I'm not quite sure how to prevent this from going on forever as my encryption loop looks similar except it has only one if statement. Please help me solve this problem.

```
while i < len(content):

        character = content[i]
        position = alpha.find(character)

        key2 = alpha.find(key[i % len(key)])
        key4 = alpha.find(key1[i % len(key1)])
        nposition = position - key2 - key4

        if nposition > len(alpha)-1:
            nposition = nposition - len(alpha)

        if nposition < 0:
            nposition = nposition + len(alpha)-1
        decipher = alpha[nposition]
        i = i + i
        output = output + decipher
    efile = open(filename2, 'w')
    efile.write(output)
    efile.close()
```

Comment: Where do you initialise `i`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your endless loop is probably this line:

```
i = i + i
```

Since your `i` is probably initialized with `0` it will never increase.
I guess you've just made a typo and needless to say that ...

```
i = i + 1
```

... will solve your issue.